# How to upgrade Torbjorn's turret?

Tags: overwatch

**How to upgrade Torbjorn's turret ?**

According to the [turret's wikia page](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Build_Turret),

> Turrets require 100 Scrap to level up.

But there is no explanation of **how** to do it. I tried to place an other turret with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, but it replacing the actual turret by an other level 1 turret.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pull out your hammer (default 2 key for PCs) and whack your turret a few times. A progress circle should show up on your HUD around the turret icon and after 5 strikes on a fully built level 1 turret, it will be upgraded to level 2.

Be aware that any hammer strikes on the turret while it is damaged will repair the turret and not upgrade it.

Additionally, level 2 turrets automatically upgrade to level 3 while Molten Core is active. Placing a new turret during Molten Core will not upgrade it instantly to level 3, but once you hit it enough times to upgrade to level 2, it will turn to level 3 for the remainder of Molten Core.

Comment: This is one of the things Overwatch forgets to explain. I guess they expected people to come from Team Fortress 2 which has the same mechanic for the Engineer class.

Comment: As for scrap: Scrap is only used to create armor packs.

Comment: Also worth noting that the turret can go to level 3 while Torbjorn has Molten Core active, but any other time the max is level 2.

Answer (score 10):

**Normal**:

- Max level of turret: 2
- Upgrading the turret

  - Equipping your hammer and smacking the turret upgrades it slowly
  - Takes 5 hits to upgrade to level 2
- The turret's HP must be full in order to upgrade it.  If an enemy damages your turret, you will have to repair first in order to upgrade.

**Molten Core (Torbjorn's Ultimate)**:

- Max level of turret: 3
- Upgrading the turret

  - Equipping your hammer and smacking the turret upgrades it quickly
  - Takes 5 hits to upgrade to level 2
  - Upon hitting level 2, the turret automatically upgrades to level 3 so long as Molten Core is still active.
  - If a turret already exists and is level 2, it will automatically upgrade to level 3 when Molten Core is activated.
  - When Molten Core expires, the turret will automatically revert back to level 2.
- If you place a turret in Molten Core mode, it will start at level 1, but will take significantly less time to upgrade to level 2, as Molten Core also speeds up your hammer attack animation so you can upgrade faster. When it hits level 2 it will automatically upgrade to level 3.

As a final note, it is imperative that you get your turret to level 2 in Molten Core mode. There is NO difference between a level 1 turret with or without Molten Core, so getting it to level 2 should be a priority.

Comment: Does this mean that a turret can remain level 3 after the ultimate if the turret is constructed during the ultimate, or is level 3 only ever during Molten Core?

Comment: @DavidLord After Molten Core expires, level 3s are automatically reverted to level 2. You can only upgrade to level 3 in Molten Core. I'll edit the answer.